# Unable to display everything in C using fprintf and fflush

Tags: c, printf, fflush

I am having trouble understanding why I can see some output but cannot see the output for certain other lines of the code below. I am using [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/) and C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "papi.h"

#define INDEX 100

static void test_fail(char *file, int line, char *call, int retval);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    extern void dummy(void *);
    float matrixa[INDEX][INDEX], matrixb[INDEX][INDEX], mresult[INDEX]    [INDEX];
    float real_time, proc_time, mflops;
    long long flpins;
    int retval, status = 0;
    int i,j,k;
    long_long values[1];

    FILE *file; 
    file = fopen("output.txt","w"); 

    retval = PAPI_library_init(PAPI_VER_CURRENT);
    int EventSet = PAPI_NULL;
    PAPI_create_eventset(&EventSet);
    if(PAPI_add_event(EventSet, PAPI_L1_DCM) != PAPI_OK)
    {
        fprintf(file,"PAPI failed to add Load/Store instructions\n");
    }

    if (PAPI_state(EventSet, &status) != PAPI_OK)
        fprintf(file,"PAPI fail\n");

    fprintf(file, "State is now %d\n", status);
    if (PAPI_start(EventSet) != PAPI_OK)
        fprintf(file,"PAPI fail\n");

    if (PAPI_state(EventSet, &status) != PAPI_OK)
        fprintf(file,"PAPI fail\n");

    fprintf(file, "State is now %d\n", status);

    /* Initialize the Matrix arrays */
    for ( i=0; i<INDEX; i++ ){
        mresult[0][i] = 0.0;
        matrixa[0][i] = matrixb[0][i] = rand()*(float)1.1; }

    if((retval=PAPI_flops( &real_time, &proc_time, &flpins, &mflops))<PAPI_OK)
        test_fail(__FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_flops", retval);

    for (i=0;i<INDEX;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<INDEX;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<INDEX;k++)
            {
                mresult[i][j]=mresult[i][j] + matrixa[i][k]*matrixb[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    if((retval=PAPI_flops( &real_time, &proc_time, &flpins, &mflops))        <PAPI_OK)
    {
        test_fail(__FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_flops", retval);
    }

    fprintf(file,"Real_time:\t%f\nProc_time:\t%f\nTotal flpins:\t%lld \nMFLOPS:\t\t%f\n",
            real_time, proc_time, flpins, mflops); //cannot see this output in the `output.txt` file
    fflush(file);
    fprintf(file,"%s\tPASSED\n", __FILE__);
    fflush(file);
    fclose(file);

    PAPI_shutdown();
    exit(0);
}

static void test_fail(char *file, int line, char *call, int retval){
}
```

In the output file, I only see the lines for "State is now". I don't see the outputs for `"Real_time:\t%f\nProc_time:\t%f\nTotal flpins:\t%lld \nMFLOPS` and the other outputs. I tried to use `fflush`, but that didn't help either. Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Don't you find it a little odd to name an output file pointer `infile`?

Comment: The code `for ( i=0; i<INDEX*INDEX; i++ ){
  mresult[0][i] = 0.0;
  matrixa[0][i] = matrixb[0][i] = rand()*(float)1.1; }` is dubious; I wouldn't trust it an inch since it writes out of bounds.  It might work, but it isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: I fixed that, but the output is the same

Comment: Have you added any code to `test_fail()` so you know whether the tests are failing?  Is the program terminating normally?  Could it be failing in `PAPI_flops()`?  You said you 'fixed the initialization loop'; how did you fix it?

Comment: Hmmm…the fix should be more like:  `for (i = 0; i < INDEX; i++){ for (j = 0; j < INDEX; j++) {
        mresult[i][j] = 0.0;
        matrixa[i][j] = matrixb[i][j] = rand()*(float)1.1;
}
}`  However, that just means you're using unitialized data; it shouldn't be crashing.